# How to specify RSA padding in Python pycrypto

Tags: java, python, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I got a pice of java RSA decrypt code, now I want to express in Python pycrypto.
but I got different ciphertext although using same private key, and server only access ciphertext that encrypt by java.

I seach google, it look like cause of padding.
I am not familiar with RSA, my current solution is that execute java code in tomcat, Python call it through http request.

but I still want to encrypt direct in Python code.

in java code:

```
public static String encrypt(String paramString)throws Exception
{
    return Base64Utils.encode(RSAUtils.encryptByPrivateKey(paramString.getBytes(), "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"));
}

public static byte[] encryptByPrivateKey(byte[] paramArrayOfByte, String paramString)throws Exception
{ 
    paramString = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(Base64Utils.decode(paramString));
    paramString = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePrivate(paramString);
    Cipher localCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");//like this padding
    localCipher.init(1, paramString);
    int k = paramArrayOfByte.length;
    ByteArrayOutputStream localByteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int j = 0;
    int i = 0;
    if (k - j > 0)
    {
      if (k - j > 117) {}
      for (paramString = localCipher.doFinal(paramArrayOfByte, j, 117);; paramString = localCipher.doFinal(paramArrayOfByte, j, k - j))
      {
        localByteArrayOutputStream.write(paramString, 0, paramString.length);
        i += 1;
        j = i * 117;
        break;
      }
    }
    paramArrayOfByte = localByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    localByteArrayOutputStream.close();
    return paramArrayOfByte;
}
```

---

in Python code:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5
from base64 import b64decode, b64encode

def encrypt(msg):
    key = "MIICdgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFA..."
    key = b64decode(key)
    private_key = RSA.importKey(key)
    cipher = PKCS1_v1_5.new(private_key)
    return b64encode(cipher.encrypt(msg))
```

---

```
java.encrypt("159742081"):
first time: GBn6RGIeEp8j/n35CgT5DdMmrvvNBtVCFQikO0vfJaYYrpEzBZ/F+5PkFLpzLDtYvQrj0Q/x/Fdxz3BtbEdLq57WFxB5MvkFxerWVeplA2vdlD7m+dgjsWyxBSbcVV1QX3UBNp+T3DtxL6uGuWUNxucy9yB5TOD3xCNchzGCnSU=
second time: GBn6RGIeEp8j/n35CgT5DdMmrvvNBtVCFQikO0vfJaYYrpEzBZ/F+5PkFLpzLDtYvQrj0Q/x/Fdxz3BtbEdLq57WFxB5MvkFxerWVeplA2vdlD7m+dgjsWyxBSbcVV1QX3UBNp+T3DtxL6uGuWUNxucy9yB5TOD3xCNchzGCnSU=

python.encrypt('159742081'):
first time:K5VXCDAPZ5yg0/UFT6mLdDOlYAI0n15HR9I60ZMntyHIItUDK7mnb67oX5BzZpx+j6OH8nfeZFPPfxRKpk83m4uN7Gw0TZTuN0eajRa2Jg79ctumBqmzCQM/05UH3wCMouVbvFu31O4PLBHqcmJNuJCOiAJE98wMKIwdS7ewv/4
second time:UWWdt1WcI0UOovXb7hH1CqK0RJWSJ4uVCOJ0wjtzPu8JB1cAOu+JaWDBjh6PMWWdi6Osb2cnOddYdgUHoMiTUieAIbj2jaXXxKzxaNlqDAGNRLZUthZXqMPEdpZ91Jagus9OS/soJBP/Vkz6i1lqpriDsm5CqVsSr+Bz+Ro7+Vo=
```

for same plaintext, java.encrypt return same ciphertext, however python.encrypt return different ciphertext in everytime.

Comment: Encryption is done with the public key and decryption is done with the private key. If you want to sign something, then you'll do that with the private key and verify the signature with the public key. That's the minimum that you have to understand. Both Java and pycrypto have different classes for encryption and digital signatures. Please use the appropriate classes.

Comment: Encrypting something with a private key in pycrypto should actually encrypt it with the public key, because the API is wired that way and because the public key can be extracted from the private key.

Answer (score 0):

I absolutely don't get what you're trying to do in the Java code, but it is not going right.

PKCS#1 v1.5 padding for encryption uses at least 8 bytes set to a random value in the range 1..255. This means that the outcome after modular exponentiation is completely random within the range 0 to N (the modulus). So each time you encrypt, using either Java or Python, the result should be completely random. This is required for the cipher to be IND_CPA secure; you would distinguish between two identical plaintext otherwise.

There is one good way to test encryption: decrypt it and see if you get the same binary plaintext. You should be able to test this cross-platform.